# Stride understanding

Tags: swift

I have this code I took from some place :

```
    for y in (0 as CGFloat).stride(from: 0.0, to: rect.height, by: elementSize)
```

**problems :**

1. What is that? `stride` should look like `for i in stride(from: 1, to: 10, by: 3)`
2. It gives errors of course, **how can I make it work** for `Swift 3` where `y` is a `CGFloat` ? when using these arguments in the *right form* I get errors about stride being taking only `Ints`?

Comment: `for i in stride(from: 1, to: 10, by: 3)` *is* the correct form in Swift 3. In your case just make sure that all arguments are of the same type `CGFloat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1). That is not Swift 3

2).

```
for y : CGFloat in stride(from: 0.0, to: 10.0, by: 0.5)
{
    print(y)
}
```

PS: The loop goes up to 9.5. If you need to reach 10.0 you need

```
for y : CGFloat in stride(from: 0.0, through: 10.0, by: 0.5) { ...
```